# Click image whose alt is example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have images which are wrapped in a div a class. The 'alt' attribute of these images are different.

When I click on image whose 'alt' is "Example", it should take me to the webpage whose url is "www.google.com".

How I can bind to the click event using alt attribute and implement this logic?

Is it possible to do so using JQuery or Javascript?

Here is my code, but it is not working. How can I fix this code?

```
$('img[alt="Example"]').on("click", "img", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location = 'www.google.com';
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery or Javascript onclick with img alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122335/jquery-or-javascript-onclick-with-img-alt-attribute)

Comment: You are using event delegation of an event on `img`s inside `img[...]`. Since there is no `img`s inside `img[...]`, you event binding is useless as it is bound for element that doesn't exist.

Comment: ...If you want to use event delegation you should bind the event on a container of your element such as in [**Alive to Die's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46124195/6647153) bellow: set it on `document` or another closer container.

Answer (score 3):

***You can do:-***

```
$('img[alt="Example"]').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = 'www.google.com';
});
```

***Example:-***

```js
$('img[alt="Example"]').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = 'www.google.com';
});
```

```css
img{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="Example" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/007AFF/billie-holiday-filled">
<br><br>
<img alt="MyExample" src="https://a.deviantart.net/avatars/c/r/crussong.png?15">
```

***Or if images created dynamically:-***

```
$(document).on("click", 'img[alt="Example"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = 'www.google.com';
});
```

***Example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').html('<img alt="Example" src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/007AFF/billie-holiday-filled"><br><br><img alt="MyExample" src="https://a.deviantart.net/avatars/c/r/crussong.png?15">');
});
$(document).on("click", 'img[alt="Example"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = 'www.google.com';
});
```

```css
img{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img[alt="Example"]').click( function (e) {
      document.location = 'http://www.google.com';
  });
```

Comment: Are you doing to explain your answer? I'm sure the OP would like to know why this method is being suggested and why the current attempt isn't functioning as expected...

Comment: @NewToJS: nope.

Comment: Well the source code might be good but isn't very helpful for those who wish to learn from it and avoid future mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unneccessary event-delegation, you can remove it by removing the `"img"` inside the `.on(`, also, add `https://` to the url:

```js
$('img[alt="Example"]').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location = 'https://www.google.com';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="Example" src="http://placeskull.com/300/300">
```